# video record feature objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to record a video on an iPad. I have the following code which brings up the record screen, however I want to add a time limit to this (20 seconds to be precise).

Although I have code below, I'd happily change it if there is a better way.

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
picker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Since you are using apple's camera buttons, you have no control over the stop/start function. For that you have to implement your own record on/off button and put logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a 20 second timer once the user starts recording. If the stop button is pressed before the timer expires, kill the timer. If the timer hits zero then you can  `[[videoController captureManager] stopRecording];`

Comment: is there anyway of detecting when the record button is pressed in the camera view? atm i can get timer working but i have to start it before the camera view is loaded and stop it when the user exits the view

Comment: Sure. You use the startVideoCapture http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/startVideoCapture

Comment: For a good in-depth look at this subject, try this great tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios